# How can you tell if a docking station will support video output with a USB Type-A "data-transfer only" port?

Tags: usb, video, hp-pavilion, docking-station

I have started to see manufacturers start to use lower quality USB ports that are "data-transfer only" this obviously won't support video output on it's own however I wanted to see if there was anything to look for in a docking station that would indicate it can support video output through this type of USB port

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "video over USB-A port". Unlike alternative modes for USB Type-C ports, Type-A ports are strictly USB data ports.

The way how the video output is implemented in docks with USB Typa-A-B ports is via special USB devices that bridge standard USB data stream into HDMI/DVI/whatever. These are USB devices that are connected to downstream ports of USB 3.x hubs, and most prominent maker is [DisplayLink](https://www.displaylink.com/products/usb-adapters). To operate, these devices need special DisplayLink USB Graphics drivers.

> How can you tell if a docking station will support video output with a
> USB Type-A “data-transfer only” port?

To answer this direct question, you don't need to tell anything. If a product with original Type-A cable (captive or not) does have HDMI/DVI/VGA output ports, this product will support video output within limitations of built-in DisplayLink chips. However, if a dock has a native USB-C port or captive Type-C cable and you want to use it with some A-to-C little adapter, there is no guarantee that any video will be supported.